# How to use setInterval in Javascript [Chrome Extension] development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to make chrome extensions and the project that I'm working on is a 'Clock' in a new tab.

Issue: I'm able to retrieve the current time, but I'm unable to refresh the page every second.
How can I fix this?

main.js

```
setInterval(function () {
  var d = new Date();

  const h = d.getHours();
  const m = d.getMinutes();
  const s = d.getSeconds();

  // Current Time w/ format
  const cFormat = h + ":" + m;

  const cTime = document.getElementById("cTime");
  cTime.textContent = cFormat;
}, 1000);
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "ClockTab",
    "description": "Clock.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "persistent": true,
    "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>","activeTab","tabs"],
    "action" : {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "main.js",
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "css": ["style.css","popup.css"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "main.js", "popup.js","dateTime.js"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "matches": ["http://*/*"]
    }]
}
```

index.html

```
<div id="cTime"></div>
```

Comment: `"background": … "service_worker": "main.js"` doesn't look like a script running in your html page.

Comment: Your code would run fine from a webpage perspective. Not sure how Chrome extensions work. You don't really need to refresh the page, the value will just keep overwriting itself, which will give you the same effect. Make sure that you are actually running the function when you intend to. Pasting this into a codepen makes it run just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for setTimeout allowing for the clock to refresh every second which only occurs after the page loads.

main.js

```
function start() {

  // Clock
  function getTime() {
    var d = new Date();

    const h = d.getHours();
    const m = d.getMinutes();
    const s = d.getSeconds();

    // Current Time w/ format
    const cFormat = h + ":" + m;

    const cTime = document.getElementById("cTime");
    cTime.textContent = cFormat;

    setTimeout(function () {
      getTime();
    }, 1000);
  }

  getTime();
}

window.addEventListener("load", start);
```